# statsmodels GLM Negative Binomial autoregressive covariance type

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, covariance

I am trying to utilize a statsmodels GLM with family of Negative Binomial to model time series data. I have gotten the model to work fine with the default covariance type of nonrobust, but I would like to use the `cov_type` of `hac_groupsum`.

Here is the link to the options for cov_type:
https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLSResults.get_robustcov_results.html

However I keep getting an error when I define the `cov_kwds`. I have tried using the index of `X`, the Time variable of `X`, and creating a list, array, and DataFrame of integers from 1 to 73 for the time keyword.

Here is the code that works

```
neg_bin = sm.GLM(y, X,family=sm.families.NegativeBinomial(alpha=aux_olsr_results.params[0])).fit()
print(neg_bin.summary())
```

and here is the code that gives me an error using a DataFrame of integers

```
time = np.array(range(1,74))
time = pd.DataFrame(time, columns = ['Time'])
neg_bin = sm.GLM(y, X,family=sm.families.NegativeBinomial(alpha=aux_olsr_results.params[0]
                                                         )).fit(cov_kwds = {'time' : time
                                                                           ,'maxlags': 5}
                                                               ,cov_type = 'hac-groupsum')
print(neg_bin.summary())
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-107-cf6c22076bb1> in <module>
      4                                                          )).fit(cov_kwds = {'time' : time
      5                                                                            ,'maxlags': 5}
----> 6                                                                ,cov_type = 'hac-groupsum')
      7 print(neg_bin.summary())

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\genmod\generalized_linear_model.py in fit(self, start_params, maxiter, method, tol, scale, cov_type, cov_kwds, use_t, full_output, disp, max_start_irls, **kwargs)
   1025             return self._fit_irls(start_params=start_params, maxiter=maxiter,
   1026                                   tol=tol, scale=scale, cov_type=cov_type,
-> 1027                                   cov_kwds=cov_kwds, use_t=use_t, **kwargs)
   1028         else:
   1029             self._optim_hessian = kwargs.get('optim_hessian')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\genmod\generalized_linear_model.py in _fit_irls(self, start_params, maxiter, tol, scale, cov_type, cov_kwds, use_t, **kwargs)
   1188                                  self.scale,
   1189                                  cov_type=cov_type, cov_kwds=cov_kwds,
-> 1190                                  use_t=use_t)
   1191 
   1192         glm_results.method = "IRLS"

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\genmod\generalized_linear_model.py in __init__(self, model, params, normalized_cov_params, scale, cov_type, cov_kwds, use_t)
   1472                 cov_kwds = {}
   1473             get_robustcov_results(self, cov_type=cov_type, use_self=True,
-> 1474                                   use_t=use_t, **cov_kwds)
   1475 
   1476     @cached_data

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\covtype.py in get_robustcov_results(self, cov_type, use_t, **kwds)
    336         if adjust_df:
    337             # need to find number of groups
--> 338             tt = (np.nonzero(time[1:] < time[:-1])[0] + 1)
    339             self.n_groups = n_groups = len(tt) + 1
    340         res.cov_params_default = sw.cov_nw_groupsum(self, maxlags, time,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py in f(self, other)
    773             if not self._indexed_same(other):
    774                 raise ValueError(
--> 775                     "Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects"
    776                 )
    777             new_data = dispatch_to_series(self, other, op, str_rep)

ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects
```

here is the error I get when I replace time with X.index

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UFuncTypeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-109-77dde8cd9c9d> in <module>
      4                                                          )).fit(cov_kwds = {'time' : X.index
      5                                                                            ,'maxlags': 5}
----> 6                                                                ,cov_type = 'hac-groupsum')
      7 print(neg_bin.summary())

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\genmod\generalized_linear_model.py in fit(self, start_params, maxiter, method, tol, scale, cov_type, cov_kwds, use_t, full_output, disp, max_start_irls, **kwargs)
   1025             return self._fit_irls(start_params=start_params, maxiter=maxiter,
   1026                                   tol=tol, scale=scale, cov_type=cov_type,
-> 1027                                   cov_kwds=cov_kwds, use_t=use_t, **kwargs)
   1028         else:
   1029             self._optim_hessian = kwargs.get('optim_hessian')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\genmod\generalized_linear_model.py in _fit_irls(self, start_params, maxiter, tol, scale, cov_type, cov_kwds, use_t, **kwargs)
   1188                                  self.scale,
   1189                                  cov_type=cov_type, cov_kwds=cov_kwds,
-> 1190                                  use_t=use_t)
   1191 
   1192         glm_results.method = "IRLS"

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\genmod\generalized_linear_model.py in __init__(self, model, params, normalized_cov_params, scale, cov_type, cov_kwds, use_t)
   1472                 cov_kwds = {}
   1473             get_robustcov_results(self, cov_type=cov_type, use_self=True,
-> 1474                                   use_t=use_t, **cov_kwds)
   1475 
   1476     @cached_data

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\covtype.py in get_robustcov_results(self, cov_type, use_t, **kwds)
    340         res.cov_params_default = sw.cov_nw_groupsum(self, maxlags, time,
    341                                         weights_func=weights_func,
--> 342                                         use_correction=use_correction)
    343         res.cov_kwds['description'] = descriptions['HAC-Groupsum']
    344     else:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\stats\sandwich_covariance.py in cov_nw_groupsum(results, nlags, time, weights_func, use_correction)
    859     '''
    860 
--> 861     xu, hessian_inv = _get_sandwich_arrays(results)
    862 
    863     #S_hac = S_nw_panel(xw, weights, groupidx)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\stats\sandwich_covariance.py in _get_sandwich_arrays(results, cov_type)
    238         elif hasattr(results.model, 'score_obs'):
    239             xu = results.model.score_obs(results.params)
--> 240             hessian_inv = np.linalg.inv(results.model.hessian(results.params))
    241         else:
    242             xu = results.model.wexog * results.wresid[:, None]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\genmod\generalized_linear_model.py in hessian(self, params, scale, observed)
    579 
    580         factor = self.hessian_factor(params, scale=scale, observed=observed)
--> 581         np.multiply(self.exog.T, factor, out=tmp.T)
    582         return -tmp.T.dot(self.exog)
    583 

UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'multiply' output from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') with casting rule 'same_kind'
```

Comment: try to use an array as `time`, `'time' : np.asarray(time)`  There might be a missing conversion to numpy arrays in the code

Comment: @Josef Get the following error when I put that
`UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'multiply' output from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') with casting rule 'same_kind'`

Comment: Do you get the same error message also without specifying `cov_type`? My guess is that there is something wrong with handling your dtype, but I cannot see what it would be. Can you provide a simple working example? Preferably with opening an issue for statsmodels https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/new/choose so we can make this more robust.